# Rspec Output Format: Documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I run `rspec` with `rake rspec` and my tests are not ok, I get an error message. However, when my tests are ok, I just get '..'. No other output. How can I get it to print something like:

```
A User .... can only have one name
A User .... can ...
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

From the `rspec` help page

```
$ rspec --help
Usage: rspec [options] [files or directories]

    -f, --format FORMATTER           Choose a formatter
                                       [p]rogress (default - dots)
                                       [d]ocumentation (group and example names)
                                       [h]tml
                                       [t]extmate
                                       custom formatter class name
```

Pass the `-f` parameter. Instead of

```
$ rake rspec
```

run

```
$ rspec spec --format d
```

or short format:

```
$ rspec -fd
```

If you want the configuration to be permanent, create a `.rspec` file in the root of your project and write there the configurations.

Comment: rspec -fd if you want it short and sweet. rspec -c -fd if you would like to see the output in colour on your screen :)

Comment: You can also make this options default putting them into your `.rspec` file. I have `--color --tty --format documentation` (by one --option per line).

Answer (score 20):

Inside your `spec/spec_helper`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.formatter = :documentation
end
```

so you don't have to run the flag everytime.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
rspec spec --format documentation
```

Comment: I would argue that it does - the command in question does exactly what the question asked. Nevertheless, there was already an (accepted) answer that stated the same thing, so this answer doesn't add any real value.